# What does "nilpotent" in a "nilpotent group" mean?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

It seems to have nothing to do with the usual nilpotency, i.e. $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}:x^n=0$.

Actually I think the latter only makes sense in a ring or more rich structure. I tried to relate some examples, but examples like Heisenberg group or unitriangular matrices is in no way nilpotent in $M_n(R)$.

Another guess would be to think of the central series as some kind of power of the group. I don't know whether this is right.

So where does the terminology come from?

Comment: Are you asking for the definition of *nilpotent group*?

Comment: @GitGud, actually no. I am trying to compare it to the common nilpotency concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nilpotent groups (of class $n$) yield the equality $[\ldots[[x_0,\;x_1],\;x_2],\;\ldots,\;x_n]=1$; nilpotent rings yield the equality  $x_0x_1\ldots x_n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think it is right. Just denote $H*K=[H,K]$ for subgroups $H,K\subset G$, and the condition means $\exists n:G^n={e}$.